# Erro PictureBox.Image <> My.Resources.user_add

Tags: vb.net, operadores

Olá, estou desenvolvendo meu TCC e tem um erro que não consigo solucionar... Abaixo segue o código:

```
If (imgAluno.Image <> My.Resources.user_add) Then
```

Ou seja, quero que o programa entre no "If" apenas se a imagem que estiver no PictureBox chamado imgAluno não for a imagem user_add, que está nas resources do projeto, mas com esse código acima eu obtenho o seguinte erro:

**Operator '<>' is not defined for types 'Image' and 'Bitmap'**

Já tentei o código abaixo, mas também não deu certo...

```
If (Not imgAluno.Image.Equals(My.Resources.user_add)) Then
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente você está tentando incluir operadores em objetos.Tente usar da seguinte forma:

```
If Not Object.ReferenceEquals(imgAluno.Image, My.Resources.user_add) Then 

End If
```

Comment: Obrigado, agora sim funcionou!